# Error when checking sensitivty and specificity of a cross validated svm

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have been performing KFold cross validation on some data (RBF SVM). I have this code in order to check the true positive rate and false positive rate. Sometimes this code throws up an error. I've noticed the error comes about whenever the random shuffling in the cross validation creates a set of all of one class, because that's where it stops running. For example:

```
sensitivity = 1.0
specificity = 0.0
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] predicted
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] actual
```

At first I thought this error was due to the fact that it would be dividing by zero so I tried to fix it with an if statement. But it still gives me this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-0339ebc92e19> in <module>()
     10 
     11     tn = float(cm[0][0])/np.sum(cm[0])
---> 12     if np.sum(cm[1]) == 0:
     13         tp = 0
     14     else:

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I'm completely lost on what the problem is or how to fix it. The code in quesion is below:

```
for i, (train, test) in enumerate(kf_total):
    y_pred = clf.fit(val[train], y[train]).predict(val[test])
    print y_pred,"predicted"
    print y[test], "actual"
    cm = confusion_matrix(y[test], y_pred)

    tn = float(cm[0][0])/np.sum(cm[0])
    if np.sum(cm[1]) == 0:
        tp = 0
    else:
        tp = float(cm[1][1])/np.sum(cm[1])

    print "sensitivity =", tp
    print "specificity =", tn
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case a dimension of predicted * actual would be 1x1, because there is only one class available - zero. Addressing to such matrix element 1 would generate out of bound error.

Comment: How can I fix this? It doesn't give the error when it predicts all zeroes and the actual contains a one

Comment: Realised how to solve the problem! I've started using stratified kfold so that I have no folds with only one class in

Comment: `if np.sum(y[test]) == 0:` for examle. [Good explanation on confusion matrix in sklearn](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95209/how-can-i-interpret-sklearn-confusion-matrix)